# How can I click an anchor tag inside the second li with Protractor?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

```
<ul ng-init="ptab = 1">
    <li ng-class="{active:ptab===1}" class="active">
        <a class="info" ng-click="ptab = 1">GENERAL INFORMATION</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{active:ptab===2}">
        <a class="info" ng-click="ptab = 2">SKILLS</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{active:ptab===3}">
        <a class="info" ng-click="ptab = 3">PATHWAYS</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

That's my HTML. I want to click the second one called `SKILLS` with Protractor and I have

`$$('.profile-top ul li').get(1).click()`

But I think that clicks the `li`, not the `a`. How can I click the `a`?

Comment: element(by.linkText("SKILLS")).click()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to do it with `css` you'll can do:

```
$$('.profile-top ul li a').get(1).click();
```

or use a different locator, as recommended by @Barney :

```
element(by.linkText('SKILLS')).click();
```